# Small amount of side scroll on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm not much of a programmer, but love to figure things out for myself. But now I have stumbled upon a little bug or mistake, which I can't wrap my head around.

When viewing my new site on an iPhone or small (Safari) browser, there is some grey area on the right sight. Its so frustrating.

Hope you guys can help me..

http://fluxx.tv/v2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5GeT.png

Answer (score 0):

its browser scrollbar it comes when the page is bigger than the screen. two options are make the content very small or add `overflow: hidden` to your body or the container